# pandas dataframe column string parsing

Tags: pandas, string, dataframe

I have a DF in which one of the columns has strings of the form

```
0 word1|category1 word2|category2

1 word3|category3 word4|category4 word2|category2 ..

2 word1|category1 word4|category4 word3|category3 ..
```

where `"word1|category1 word4|category4 word3|category3 .."` is a string

I need an output dictionary mapping that maps unique set of words to their respective categories.

I tried using `series.apply(ast.literal_eval)` but it throws an invalid syntax error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need dictionaries for each row use nested list comprehension:

```
df['col'] = [dict(y.split('|') for y in x.split()) for x in df['col']]
print (df)
                                                 col
0       {'word1': 'category1', 'word2': 'category2'}
1  {'word3': 'category3', 'word4': 'category4', '...
2  {'word1': 'category1', 'word4': 'category4', '...
```

Or if need one big dictionary from all values use [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with [`Series.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html), create 2 columns DataFrame and convert to dictionary:

```
d = df['col'].str.split().explode().str.split('|', expand=True).set_index(0)[1].to_dict()
print (d)
{'word1': 'category1', 'word2': 'category2', 'word3': 'category3', 'word4': 'category4'}
```

Another alterntive:

```
d = dict(df['col'].str.split().explode().str.split("|").to_numpy())
```